# Test in init.rc if a property is unset

Tags: android, linux, init

How can you check if a property is unset in init.rc:

In the following example test.b is not yet set

```
on property:test.a=1 && test.b=<unset>
#    do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading `queue_property_triggers`[1](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/system/core/init/init_parser.c#517) it seems that you can't. You'll probably need to change your code logic.